# Pandas read_excel ignores blank column that I need to keep

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

long time user of stackoverflow, first time poster, so all help is appreciated :)

TLDR;
**Is there a parameter for read_excel that I am missing to keep all columns (i.e. not remove any, even if they are blank)?**

Issue in detail:
When using read_excel, I have a blank column as the first column in one of the sheets I am reading in. This blank column is then removed from the dataframe, which in turn messes up the rest of the code as it relies on the column index's being the same between the sheets. I cannot code around it due to the rest of the sheets following this standardized format.
The code following this is correct. When adding a filler value into the blank column, the code works. This is not a solution due to logic needed for blank values in column index 0 (column A) being set to a certain value.

[Pandas.read_excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
   "test.xlsx,
   sheet_name = "MYSHEET",
   # Missing parameter that i cannot figure out
)

# Code following this is looping row by row, column by column of each item in dataframe to get desired output
```

Input excel file has double headers, and columns A, B, C are getting pivoted into header values (hence I need to keep blank columns)

Comment: What about `usecols`?

Comment: @BigBen for ```usecols```, for the syntax, how would I specify columns A through MV? I found some examples online but they do not seem to work. Example: ```usecols=["A", "MV"]``` does not work.

Comment: `usecols='A:MV'`, as explained in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: Thank you - That seems to have fixed the problem. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can use `usecols`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(
   "test.xlsx",
   sheet_name="MYSHEET",
   usecols="A:MV"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue.

```
df = pd.read_excel(
   "test.xlsx,
   sheet_name = "MYSHEET",
   skip_blank_lines=False
)
```

Comment: Sadly, it does not. Any other options?




TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'

Comment: Looks like skip_blank_lines was deprecated from read_excel(). It still works with read_csv().

Comment: Ah that would make sense then. I really do appreciate the help!