# Pandas read_excel no longer adheres single empty column

Tags: python, pandas

I came across this post [Pandas read_excel ignores blank column that I need to keep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917839/pandas-read-excel-ignores-blank-column-that-i-need-to-keep) and I am facing the same issue lately on my application which was working fine. looks like add_excel() is ignoring the empty column which I need to override the existing values in the database. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a complete column of just `' '` or `'\n'` or `'\t'` literals?

Another way could be naming a column:
say a df x contains columns 'a', 'b' with values

Could this work?

```py
x.loc['c'] = pd.Series([None*len(x.loc['a'])])
```

Seems stupid, but most stupid things work sometimes...